# How to parse serverless.yml file in script

Tags: serverless-framework

I need to read the `serverless.yml` config for use in some test mocks.

The following worked until a recent change:

```
const serverless = new Serverless()
await serverless.init()
const service = await serverless.variables.populateService()
```

How does one read the file now? There is an astounding lack of documentation in regards to using serverless progamically.

Answer (score 1):

Well I ended up taking some code from the [AppSync emulator](https://github.com/ConduitVC/aws-utils/tree/appsync/packages/appsync-emulator-serverless) package. I am not sure it covers it does a full parsing but it does the job for me.

```
import Serverless from 'serverless'
import path from 'path'
import fs from 'fs'

class ConfigServerless extends Serverless {
  async getConfig(servicePath) {
    this.processedInput = {
      commands: [],
      options: { stage: 'dev' }
    }

    this.config.servicePath = servicePath
    this.pluginManager.setCliOptions(this.processedInput.options)
    this.pluginManager.setCliCommands(this.processedInput.commands)
    await this.service.load(this.processedInput)

    this.pluginManager.validateCommand(this.processedInput.commands)

    return this.variables
      .populateService(this.pluginManager.cliOptions)
      .then(() => {
        this.service.mergeArrays()
        this.service.setFunctionNames(this.processedInput.options)
        this.service.validate()
      })
  }
}

const normalizeResources = config => {
  if (!config.resources) {
    return config.resources
  }

  if (!config.resources.Resources) {
    return {}
  }

  if (!Array.isArray(config.resources.Resources)) {
    return config.resources
  }

  const newResources = config.resources.Resources.reduce(
    (sum, { Resources, Outputs = {} }) => ({
      ...sum,
      ...Resources,
      Outputs: {
        ...(sum.Outputs || {}),
        ...Outputs
      }
    }),
    {}
  )

  return {
    Resources: newResources
  }
}

export async function loadServerlessConfig(cwd = process.cwd()) {
  const stat = fs.statSync(cwd)
  if (!stat.isDirectory()) {
    cwd = path.dirname(cwd)
  }

  const serverless = new ConfigServerless()
  await serverless.getConfig(cwd)
  const { service: config } = serverless

  const { custom = {} } = config

  const output = {
    ...config,
    custom: {
      ...custom
    },
    resources: normalizeResources(config)
  }

  return output
}
```

Comment: For Serverless v2 you need to make these two changes: the argument to `this.service.load()` is `this.processedInput.commands` and after calling it you will have to load all the plugins explicitly using `this.pluginManager.loadAllPlugins(this.service.plugins)`